# Convolution of multiple 1D signals in a 2D matrix with multiple 1D kernels in a 2D matrix

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, convolution

I have a randomly defined `H` matrix of size `600 x 10`. Each element in this matrix `H` can be represented as `H(k,t)`.  I obtained a speech spectrogram `S` which is `600 x 597`. I obtained it using Mel features, so it should be `40 x 611` but then I used a frame stacking concept in which I stacked 15 frames together. Therefore it gave me `(40x15) x (611-15+1)` which is `600 x 597`.

Now I want to obtain an output matrix `Y` which is given by the equation based on convolution `Y(k,t) = ∑ H(k,τ)S(k,t-τ)`. The sum goes from `τ=0` to `τ=Lh-1`.  `Lh` in this case would be 597.

I don't know how to obtain `Y`. Also, my doubt is the indexing into both `H` and `S` when computing the convolution.  Specifically, for `Y(1,1)`, we have:

`Y(1,1) = H(1,0)S(1,1) + H(1,1)S(1,0) + H(1,2)S(1,-1) + H(1,3)S(1,-2) + ...`

Now, there is no such thing as negative indices in MATLAB - for example, `S(1,-1) S(1,-2)` and so on. So, what type of convolution should I use to obtain `Y`? I tried using `conv2` or `fftfilt` but I think that will not give me `Y` because `Y` must also be the size of `S`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's very easy.  That's a convolution on a 2D signal only being applied to 1 dimension.  If we assume that the variable `k` is used to access the rows and `t` is used to access the columns, you can consider each row of `H` and `S` as separate signals where each row of `S` is a 1D signal and each row of `H` is a convolution kernel.

There are two ways you can approach this problem.

## Time domain

If you want to stick with time domain, the easiest thing would be to loop over each row of the output, find the convolution of each pair of rows of `S` and `H` and store the output in the corresponding output row.  From what I can tell, there is no utility that can convolve in one dimension only given an N-D signal.... unless you go into frequency domain stuff, but let's leave that for later.

Something like:

```
Y = zeros(size(S));
for idx = 1 : size(Y,1)
    Y(idx,:) = conv(S(idx,:), H(idx,:), 'same');
end
```

For each row of the output, we perform a row-wise convolution with a row of `S` and a row of `H`.  I use the `'same'` flag because the output should be the same size as a row of `S`... which is the bigger row.

## Frequency domain

You can also perform the same computation in frequency domain.  If you know anything about the properties of convolution and the Fourier Transform, you know that convolution in time domain is multiplication in the frequency domain.  You take the Fourier Transform of both signals, multiply them element-wise, then take the Inverse Fourier Transform back.

However, you need to keep the following intricacies in mind:

1. Performing a full convolution means that the final length of the output signal is `length(A)+length(B)-1`, assuming `A` and `B` are 1D signals.  Therefore, you need to make sure that both `A` and `B` are **zero-padded** so that they both match the same size.  The reason **why** you make sure that the signals are the same size is to allow for the multiplication operation to work.
2. Once you multiply the signals in the frequency domain then take the inverse, you will see that each row of `Y` is the **full** length of the convolution.  To ensure that you get an output that is the same size as the input, you need to **trim off** some points at the beginning and at the end.  Specifically, since each kernel / column length of `H` is 10, you would have to remove the first 5 and last 5 points of each signal in the output to match what you get in the `for` loop code.
3. Usually after the inverse Fourier Transform, there are some residual complex coefficients due to the nature of the FFT algorithm.  It's good practice to use `real` to remove the complex valued parts of the results.

Putting all of this theory together, this is what the code would look like:

```
%// Define zero-padded H and S matrices
%// Rows are the same, but columns must be padded to match point #1
H2 = zeros(size(H,1), size(H,2)+size(S,2)-1);
S2 = zeros(size(S,1), size(H,2)+size(S,2)-1);

%// Place H and S at the beginning and leave the rest of the columns zero
H2(:,1:size(H,2)) = H;
S2(:,1:size(S,2)) = S;

%// Perform Fourier Transform on each row separately of padded matrices
Hfft = fft(H2, [], 2);
Sfft = fft(S2, [], 2);

%// Perform convolution
Yfft = Hfft .* Sfft;

%// Take inverse Fourier Transform and convert to real
Y2 = real(ifft(Yfft, [], 2));

%// Trim off unnecessary values
Y2 = Y2(:,size(H,2)/2 + 1 : end - size(H,2)/2 + 1);
```

`Y2` should be the convolved result and should match `Y` in the previous `for` loop code.

## Comparison between them both

If you actually want to compare them, we can.  What we'll need to do first is define `H` and `S`.  To reconstruct what I did, I generated random values with a known seed:

```
rng(123);
H = rand(600,10);
S = rand(600,597);
```

Once we run the above code for both the time domain version and frequency domain version, let's see how they match up in the command prompt.  Let's show the first 5 rows and 5 columns:

```
>> format long g;
>> Y(1:5,1:5)

ans =

          1.63740867892464          1.94924208172753          2.38365646354643          2.05455605619097          2.21772526557861
          2.04478411247085          2.15915645246324          2.13672842742653          2.07661341840867          2.61567534623066
         0.987777477630861           1.3969752201781          2.46239452105228          3.07699790208937          3.04588738611503
          1.36555260994797          1.48506871890027          1.69896157726456          1.82433906982894          1.62526864072424
          1.52085236885395          2.53506897420001          2.36780282057747          2.22335617436888          3.04025523335182

>> Y2(1:5,1:5)

ans =

      1.63740867892464          1.94924208172753          2.38365646354643          2.05455605619097          2.21772526557861
      2.04478411247085          2.15915645246324          2.13672842742653          2.07661341840867          2.61567534623066
     0.987777477630861           1.3969752201781          2.46239452105228          3.07699790208937          3.04588738611503
      1.36555260994797          1.48506871890027          1.69896157726456          1.82433906982894          1.62526864072424
      1.52085236885395          2.53506897420001          2.36780282057747          2.22335617436888          3.04025523335182
```

Looks good to me!  As another measure, let's figure out what the largest difference is between one value in `Y` and a corresponding value in `Y2`:

```
>> max(abs(Y(:) - Y2(:)))

ans =

      5.32907051820075e-15
```

That's saying that the max error seen between both outputs is in the order of 10<sup>-15</sup>.  I'd say that's pretty good.

Comment: Thanks Ray. That was indeed easy and I got the concept :)
Can you explain what would happen if I used conv2 function? 
Also, can you now write the frequency based approach part. I think that should be related to "Convolution in time domain is multiplication in frequency domain".

Comment: Using conv2 won't work because the kernel changes per row of your signal. You don't have a choice but to apply individual convolutions per row of your output matrix. Yes you are correct about the multiplication in frequency domain. However I'm currently not home but I will be later and I'll append to my post. Cool?

Comment: one more thing, when you mentioned this about the negative indices, "The "negative" indices are handled using a variety of methods... zero-padding, mirror reflecting the output, etc. MATLAB can perfectly handle that fine if you are smart and you pad your inputs first. However, by default MATLAB assumes these values are 0"

Can you elaborate on this?
If I have a matrix S, let an element be S(k,t-tau), what will MATLAB do if t-tau is negative? I was getting an error but you said its assumed to be zero by default.

Comment: @shubhamsharma - `conv` **internally** handles negative indices to be zero.  Specifically, if `tau` was negative, `conv` will silently assume these are zero.  Obviously if you use negative indices normally in MATLAB syntax you'll get an error.  I should delete my comment as its confusing..... but did the frequency stuff help you?

Comment: Indeed, it did. I got the concept of convolution(both time and frequency domain).

Comment: @shubhamsharma - Great.  This also allowed me to flex my signal processing knowledge a bit!  BTW, interesting note.  The `conv` method is much faster than the `FFT` method.  My guess is because you have to compute the FFT twice and do a whole bunch of setup where as `conv` does the computations right away.  I did some timing tests on various data set sizes last night.

Comment: I came across this function arrayfun. Will using this function fasten my code? Because, now MATLAB is parallelising the operation instead of running for loops.

Comment: @shubhamsharma `arrayfun` is basically a `for` loop under the hood.  I would argue that it would be **slower** due to function call overhead.  `arrayfun` **does not** do anything in parallel.  **However**, there is an `arrayfun` version that operates on `gpuArrays` and you would need an nVidia CUDA enabled GPU for that.  Is this what you were referring to?  The only time you can do things in parallel is by using the Parallel Computing Toolbox... which `arrayfun` **does not use**.  However, you can speed up that `for` loop using `parfor` and that could give you decrease in execution time.

Comment: Yes. I am working on a nVidia CUDA enabled GPU. So, I thought arrayfun can be much faster.

Comment: @shubhamsharma - Be careful.  The amount of time it takes to transfer between Host and Device memory will be a factor.  The raw computation will certainly be faster, but transferring to and from GPU will be a bottleneck.  The only thing you can do is test it out and see if it's faster or not.  You also need to make sure the functions you use in conjunction to the function you want to run with `arrayfun` are `gpuArray` supported.  Luckily, `conv` is `gpuArray` supported.