# How to implement these multiplicative updates in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, optimization, updates

I am doing two updates for h and x given in this [paper] http://paris.cs.illinois.edu/pubs/nasser-icassp2015.pdf (You don't have to read the paper, just look for the equations 4,10 and 14 for updating h and x given on page 2 and 3).

This is the code snippet that I have tried so far. Can you tell me if its correct? Also, is there any way to optimize these for loops?

In some cases (t-tau) term was negative and MATLAB was giving an error. So, I put a condition that only implement if (t-tau)>0. Doing this is correct or is there any other way to take care of the negative indices?

```
%updates
Lh=10;
lambda = 0.1*(sum(reverberatedspeechspec(:))/(size(Y,1)*size(Y,2)));
S=reverberatedspeechspec;
W=basis_mel_act; W=gather(W); W = double(W); %W is the dictionary
%---initialization for H(RIR)----
H=rand(size(Y,1),Lh);
nmfIter = 50;

%---initialization for X(Activations)-----
W_trans=W';
X=W_trans*S; X=double(X);

Y = zeros(size(S,1));
for idx = 1 : size(Y,1)
    Y(idx,:) = filter(S(idx,:),1,H(idx,:));
end

Stilde = zeros(size(S));
Ytilde = zeros(size(S));

for iter=1:nmfIter
    % update for H
    Stilde = W*X;
    Ytilde = zeros(size(S));
    for j=1:size(Stilde,1)
        Ytilde (j,:) =  filter(Stilde(j,:),1,H(j,:));
    end
    ratio = Y./Ytilde;
    numerator = zeros(size(H));
    denominator = numerator;
    for k = 1 :size(Y,1)
        for tau = 1:Lh
            for t= 1:size(Y,2)
                if gt (t-tau , 0)
                    numerator (k,tau) = numerator(k,tau) + ratio(k,t) * Stilde(k,t-tau);
                    denominator(k,tau) = denominator (k,tau) + Stilde (k,t-tau);
                end
            end
        end
    end
    H = H .* numerator ./denominator ;

    %updating Ytilde after getting a new value for H
    for j=1:size(Stilde,1)
        Ytilde (j,:) =  filter(Stilde(j,:),1,H(j,:));
    end

    %update for X
    ratio = Y./Ytilde;
    ratio = [ratio zeros(size(Y,1),Lh)]; %zero padding Y and Ytilde for (t+tau) term in update of X.
    Product = H.' * W; % Product of H_transpose and W in th update which is equivalent to the term ∑H(k,tau)W(k,r)
    numerator = zeros(size(H));
    denominator = numerator;
    for r = 1:size(W,2)
        for t = 1:size(Y,2)
            for k = 1:size(Y,1)
                for tau = 1:Lh
                    numerator(r,t) = numerator(r,t) + ratio(k,t+tau) * Product(tau,r);
                    denominator(r,t) = denominator(r,t) + Product(tau,r) + lambda;
                end
            end
        end
    end
    X = X .* numerator ./denominator;
end
```

Comment: @rayryeng - I have tried this so far.

Comment: @speerian - If you remember this question, please help.

Comment: Uhm... why aren't you using the stuff we did together in our previous post?  That's exactly what is required for you to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087632/convolution-of-multiple-1d-signals-in-a-2d-matrix-with-multiple-1d-kernels-in-a

Comment: Actually, using "conv" or using frequency domain was not giving the desired result here(I got the concept very well), so I used the "filter" function.
Here, my concern is the right code for the updates and checking the negative index. Can you help me with that?

Comment: You can just to `t >= tau` instead of directly using the `gt` operator, but that looks fine if that's all you want me to check.

Comment: Oh. So, is the code fine? It seems to me that my code matches the updates given in the paper but I just posted it here to get it confirmed. 
Also, can I optimise the code by converting it into matrices instead of using loops? I tried doing that but I had trouble converting it into matrix form

Comment: Looking at the equations in the paper and the code you wrote, it seems to match up.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Is there a way to optimize it? Because this will take a lot of time to run on 3 hours of speech data and huge size of S,Y,W,X and H.